Flutter "flutter_app_badger" package discontinued? Alternatives?
flutter_app_badger is now marked as "discontinued".
Are there any alternatives that work as well as this package does?

Use flutter_app_badge. Fork of flutter_app_badger.

There are few options,
flutter_app_badge 

app_badge_plus

flutter_app_icon_badge

look into pub.dev for the latest versions and packages.
